# Woocommerce create order API issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ionic3

I have Woocommerce installed and my Ionic App is interacting with it through the WP Rest API. Since 2 days I have a strange issue. If I try to submit an order in the app the order is not completed and I see a 201 status without a response from server. However, the email confirmation is send out. I checked also the db and I don't see an order. 
In the app I have also a subscription module and when I submit an order for a subscription then it is processed normal and I see the order ID.

I tested this also on the website and there I don't have any issue. So, the problem is restriced only on products buy with exception of subscriptions. Do you can support me?

Comment: which API version of woocommerce you are using V2 or V3?

Comment: I use V2 version

Comment: Try V3 which is supporting subscription products

Comment: What I know noticed is that when I submit a new product direct from the admin the permalink is as follows: https://example.com/?post_type=product&#038;p=2704 and when I do this from the app or website through client portal the permalink is https://example.com/product/test-from-website-23/

Comment: update: I found out that only products can be purchased, which the owner is an administrator and not a vendor